# bulk rename all gifs of subdirectories rename() php

Tags: php, file-rename

I have a lot, but a lot of gifs (about five thousand), in several folders (categories names) inside a main folder `gifs/`

**PROBLEM**

I need to rename all the gifs for a simple correlative number. for example `image (24).gif` to `213.gif` (correlative to the main directory sequence)

I return the whole gifs listing with this function

**PHP FUNCTION**

```
 $dir = '../gifs';

function listFolderFiles($dir)
 {
   echo '<ol>';
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $i => $fileInfo) {
    if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) {
        echo '<li>' . $fileInfo->getFilename();
        if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
            listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname());
        }
        echo " - >".$i.'</li>';
       }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
  }
  listFolderFiles($dir);
  //rename('picture.gif', '1.gif');
```

this is some of the files estructures, most of all have parenthesis on their names...

```
hugs
 animaton (11).gif
 animaton (12).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (18).gif
 animaton (19).gif
 animaton (22).gif
 animaton (23).gif
 animaton (26).gif
 animaton (27).gif
 animaton (29).gif
 animaton (31).gif
 animaton (34).gif
 animaton (35).gif
 animaton (4).gif
 animaton (41).gif
 animaton (43).gif
 animaton (46).gif
 animaton (49).gif
 animaton.gif
bored
 animaton (1).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (18).gif
 animaton (19).gif
 animaton (20).gif
 animaton (25).gif
 animaton (27).gif
 animaton (29).gif
 animaton (31).gif
 animaton (33).gif
 animaton (35).gif
 animaton (36).gif
 animaton (40).gif
 animaton (41).gif
 animaton (43).gif
 animaton (45).gif
 animaton (49).gif
 animaton (5).gif
 animaton (7).gif
 animaton (9).gif
wink
 animaton (11).gif
 animaton (12).gif
 animaton (21).gif
 animaton (27).gif
 animaton (3).gif
 animaton (35).gif
 animaton (36).gif
 animaton (38).gif
 animaton (39).gif
 animaton (4).gif
 animaton (43).gif
 animaton (8).gif
sleepy
 animaton (11).gif
 animaton (12).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (14).gif
 animaton (16).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (19).gif
 animaton (20).gif
 animaton (21).gif
 animaton (22).gif
 animaton (24).gif
 animaton (26).gif
 animaton (27).gif
 animaton (29).gif
 animaton (3).gif
 animaton (32).gif
 animaton (34).gif
 animaton (35).gif
 animaton (36).gif
 animaton (37).gif
 animaton (38).gif
 animaton (39).gif
 animaton (4).gif
 animaton (40).gif
 animaton (41).gif
 animaton (45).gif
 animaton (46).gif
 animaton (49).gif
 animaton (5).gif
 animaton (6).gif
 animaton (9).gif
 animaton.gif
love
 animaton (1).gif
 animaton (11).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (14).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (18).gif
 animaton (20).gif
 animaton (21).gif
 animaton (24).gif
 animaton (25).gif
 animaton (27).gif
 animaton (28).gif
 animaton (29).gif
 animaton (38).gif
 animaton (39).gif
 animaton (4).gif
 animaton (40).gif
 animaton (41).gif
 animaton (44).gif
 animaton (48).gif
 animaton (5).gif
 animaton (7).gif
 animaton (9).gif
 animaton.gif
claps
 animaton (1).gif
 animaton (10).gif
 animaton (11).gif
 animaton (12).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (15).gif
 animaton (16).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (19).gif
 animaton (20).gif
 animaton (21).gif
 animaton (22).gif
 animaton (23).gif
 animaton (25).gif
 animaton (28).gif
 animaton (3).gif
 animaton (30).gif
 animaton (31).gif
 animaton (34).gif
 animaton (35).gif
 animaton (38).gif
 animaton (39).gif
 animaton (4).gif
 animaton (40).gif
 animaton (41).gif
 animaton (42).gif
 animaton (43).gif
 animaton (44).gif
 animaton (46).gif
 animaton (47).gif
 animaton (49).gif
 animaton (5).gif
 animaton (6).gif
 animaton (7).gif
 animaton (8).gif
scared
 animaton (1).gif
 animaton (10).gif
 animaton (12).gif
 animaton (13).gif
 animaton (15).gif
 animaton (16).gif
 animaton (17).gif
 animaton (18).gif
 animaton (21).gif
 animaton (24).gif
 animaton (33).gif
 animaton (39).gif
 animaton (40).gif
 animaton (46).gif
 animaton (6).gif
```

Comment: What’s the problem? Rather than printing the name, just use `rename()`?

Comment: @Dan  Please see my updated answer.  Thanks

Comment: Ill test it thank.you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer!!***

I have tested this, but my behavior may not be what you want.

This function will iterate recursively through every file and subfolder from the directory you give it.  It will then change the names of any file by number (consecutive count) in every folder.

I have commented out the rename() function so as to not rename stuff until you are happy with the results.  Once you uncomment out the rename() function it will rename EVERY FILE. Hence if it does not work how you want it, there is no going back. This could cause serious havoc to your folder/file structure.

***You should back up your files before proceeding just in case.***

```
$dir = '../gifs';

function listFolderFiles($dir){

  $results = new DirectoryIterator($dir);

  echo '<ul>';

  $count = 1;
  foreach($results as $fileInfo){

      if($fileInfo->isFile()){

        $oldFileName = $fileInfo->getPathname();
        $newFileName = $fileInfo->getPath() . '/' . $count . '.gif';

        //rename($oldFileName, $newFileName); //<-- Uncomment here to actually
        //rename your files.  Only do this when you are sure you are happy
        //with the results.

        echo '<li>' . 'File  Old: ' . $oldFileName . '  New: ' . $newFileName . '</li>';

        $count++;

      }

      if($fileInfo->isDir() && !$fileInfo->isDot()){

        echo '<li>' . 'Folder: ' . $fileInfo->getPathname() . '</li>';
        listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname());

      }

  }

  echo '</ul>';



}


listFolderFiles($dir);
```

Comment: I ended up renaming the files this way...but How do I get a listing number per `li`?

Comment: I was able to get  the solution with your function, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/q/49694942/9503467